# Isospin at Vertices

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, standard-model, isospin-symmetry

I want to calculate the isospin factors at each vertex for the diagram below. For me the problem is, it depends on the direction of the $\pi_0$ direction, which it shouldn't.

For the left vertex, I get a factor of $\sqrt{2/3}$ since we have $I,I_3=1,0$ and $I,I_3=1/2,1/2$ coupling to $I,I_3=3/2,1/2$ (incoming photon and proton coupling to Delta).

At the lower vertex I have, when the pion is incoming, $I,I_3=3/2,1/2$ and $I,I_3=1,0$ coupling to $I,I_3=1/2,1/2$ with an isospin factor of $-\sqrt{1/3}$, when the pion is outgoing I have $I,I_3=3/2,1/2$ and $I,I_3=1,0$ coupling to $I,I_3=1/2,1/2$ with an isospin factor of $-\sqrt{1/3}$.

At the upper vertex, for both cases I have $I,I_3=1/2,1/2$ and $I,I_3=1,0$ coupling to $I,I_3=1/2,1/2$, with an isospin factor of $-\sqrt{1/3}$.

The product of all factors depends on the direction of the pion, so what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose to write two diagrams with the pion internal line tilted to the  left, and to the  right respectively, indicating a notional, indifferent sense of momentum flow determining your Clebsch matrix elements. $\bar p$ has $I_3=-1/2$.

That is, compare cases A and B,
$$
A:\qquad \gamma\to \bar p \Delta^+ ; \qquad \bar p \to \bar p \pi^0, \qquad \Delta^+ \pi^0 \to p;\\
B:\qquad \gamma\to \bar p \Delta^+ ; \qquad \bar p \pi^0\to \bar p , \qquad \Delta^+  \to p \pi^0. 
$$
Confirm there is no difference:
$$
A:\sqrt{1/2}\qquad  \sqrt{1/3}\qquad (-\sqrt{1/3}) \\                          \\
B:\sqrt{1/2}\qquad  \sqrt{1/3}\qquad (-\sqrt{1/3}) .
$$

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I am also doing a mistake for when one particle is scattered to several ones. What exactly is the difference to when I couple several particles to a single one? In lectures we have only coupled several spins to a single one, but never "decoupled" them.

Comment: Decoupling them is running the movie backwards. You just complex conjugate the matrix element/Clebsch, but here they are all real!!

Comment: Thank you. Only one thing which confuses me a bit: The isospin factor then depends on how a vertex is rotated. Is this correct? If we have $p\gamma\to\Delta^+$ we have a different result then $\gamma\to \bar{p}\Delta^+$

Comment: Indeed, $ -\sqrt{1/3}=\langle 3/2~1/2|1/2~1/2~~ 1~0 \rangle \neq \langle 1/2~-\! 1/2~~3/2~1/2 |1~0 \rangle= \sqrt{1/2}$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but I have one more question after going through all the isospin factors. For $\Delta^+\pi^0\to p$ I get $-\sqrt{1/3}$ as you, but for $\Delta^+\to p\pi^0$ I get $\sqrt{2/3}$, meaning the product of all isospin factors is not the same. We couple $1/2,1/2$ with $1,0$ to $3/2,1/2$ and the coefficient for that is $\sqrt{2/3}$.

Comment: Apologies, I fell into your rabbit hole. The proper relations are summarized [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients#Symmetry_properties)...